# Passing build arguments in .drone.yml for docker plugin

Tags: docker, drone.io, docker-build

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM myabse

ARG SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH=com-ifx

COPY ./hue-com-ifx-front/target-server-side/com-ifx.war /opt/tomcat/webapps/${SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH}.war

CMD ["/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

When I try build the docker image like this

`sudo docker build --build-arg  SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH=mywar -t com-ifx:latest` and run the image using `sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 com-ifx:latest`

The war file copied is `mywar.war`

I tried to do the same in `.drone.yml`

```
docker:
    image: plugins/docker
    registry: registry.paas.workslan
    repo: registry.paas.workslan/ifx-prestaging/com-ifx
    build_args: 
      - SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH=mywar
    secrets: [ docker_username, docker_password ]
    tags: latest
    when:
      branch: ticket-*
  docker_publish_feature_branch:
    image: plugins/docker
    registry: registry.paas.workslan
    repo: registry.paas.workslan/ifx-prestaging/com-ifx
    secrets: [ docker_username, docker_password ]
    tags: ${DRONE_COMMIT_BRANCH}
    when:
      branch: [ticket-*]
```

But the name of the war is always `com-ifx.war`. I want it to be `mywar.war`. How should I do in this in `.drone.yml`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used two changes from your script. Which are:

In Dokerfile I used, the format $VARIABLE or "$VARIABLE" to reference the variable.

And in .drone.yml file the variable is specified as

build_args_from_env: [ VARIABLE ]

This works for me

Comment: The thread looks old, but might be helpful for someone who bumps into this issue: http://plugins.drone.io/drone-plugins/drone-docker/